# Regex to match three words separated by two commas

Tags: regex

I am trying to get at least three words  separated by two commas.I have so far managed to match two words with one comma with

```
/([A-z]|[0-9])(,{1})([A-z]|[0-9])/
```

but how can I add a comma and a word to this.I have tried repeating the same but did not work.

Comment: What language in this regular expression in?

Comment: You probably want `[a-zA-Z]` and not `[A-z]`

Comment: Appears to be javascript to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You want a `*` or `+` after the `[]` range to allow for multiple occurrences to occur (i.e. words longer than 1 character). And that rather than `([a-z]|[0-9])+` you can simply write `[a-z0-9]+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/^(?:\w+,){2,}(?:\w+)$/`

This will get you a comma separated list of at least 3 words ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).

`/^\s*(?:\w+\s*,\s*){2,}(?:\w+\s*)$/`

This is a slightly more user-friendly version of the first, allowing spaces in between words.

Comment: thanks for the help.but the regexp doesnot allow the spaces between the words likw you mentioned

Comment: [I tried it myself.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)  What example did you try?

Comment: thanks for this.I am happy with what u gave me but It seems that the first and the third words take spaces between but the second one doesnot.Foe example, (very good,not bad,very ugly) would not pass the validation but (very good,bad,very ugly) passes the validation

Comment: @NarendraChitrakar The problem with allowing spaces is that you must consider the space after the comma as possibly valid input.  If that's the case, then try `/^(?:[\w\W]+,){2,}(?:[\w\W]+)$/` which takes whitespace characters as well.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a [PERL derived regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Perl-derived_regular_expressions), as most implementations I've encountered, `/[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){2,}/` tests well against anything that has at least two commas in it, providing that the commas have something between them. The `(?:)` construct allows to group without capturing. The `{2,}` construct specifies 2 or more matches of the previous group. In javascript, you can test it:

```
/[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){2,}/.test("hello,world,whats,up,next"); // returns true

/[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){2,}/.test("hello,world"); // returns false
```

Comment: You could probably go without the `?:` in the `(?:)` construct if it's not PERL derived; but then you get captures, which I don't know if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Few general suggestions from performance perspective:

1. Don't use [ ]|[ ] clause - you can just put few character classes inside one [ ], e.g. [A-Za-z0-9]
2. Don't overuse () - usually each of them stores captured argument which requires additional overhead. If you just need to group few pieces together look for grouping operator that does not store match (it might be something like (?: ... ) )

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) its nearly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2,}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will solve your problem, 
try this

([a-zA-Z0-9],[a-zA-Z0-9],([a-zA-Z0-9]))

Comment: This will only handle single characters, e.g. a,b,c or 1,2,3.